# elegant k-smallest argmin in Matlab

Tags: matlab, min

Is there a cleaner (as in, ideally built in; I've never used Matlab so apologies if I missed something obvious) way to do k-smallest argmin in Matlab (i.e. if an array is [4,5,6,7] it should return the indexes 1,2 in that order) besides stuff like:

```
arr = [4,5,6,7];
[~, argmin1] = min(arr);
arr(argmin1) = Inf;
[~, argmin2] = min(arr);
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say we want indices of `k` smallest element in array `arr`, then:

```
arr=[4,5,6,7,2];
[~,indices]=sort(arr,'ascend');
argmin=indices(1:k);
```

If one want `k` highest values, use `descend` argument instead.

Comment: Guess I'm still not used to functions randomly adding extra return parameters if you ask for them... grr